# Не работают функции TextView

Tags: xcode, ios, objective-c

Кинул TextView на вью, указал делегат, прописал в .h <UITextViewDelegate>, через @property добавил.

Вообщем не работает ни один void

```
textViewDidBeginEditing:(UITextView *)textView
textViewDidChange:(UITextView *)textView
```

BOOL тоже не работает, пытался ограничить лимит ввода, не вышло.

```
textView:(UITextView *)textView shouldChangeTextInRange:(NSRange)range replacementText:(NSString *)text
```

Подскажите, в чём дело?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Думаю, потому что нужно еще текст вью что ваш контроллер является делегатов (textView.delegate = self или в интерфейс билдере)

Comment: Да, прописал в ViewDidLoad, заработало. Спасибо

Answer (score 1):

А вы не забыли в storyboard указать "delegate"? От textview протянуть (с зажатым ctrl) на само view...

Comment: Не забыл, сделал первым делом.

Comment: Оказалось что я кинул хвост не к той Вьюшке, вот и не работало. Ваш ответ тоже правильный. Спасибо.

Comment: он попросту аналогичный и судя по времени мы дали ответ одновременно, это просто первое что приходит в голову